# How to convert a ONNX network (generated by MatLab) to a caffemodel?

Tags: onnx

I built a Network in Matlab and exported as ONNX but I need a caffemodel. How can I convert it? I found this
https://github.com/MTlab/onnx2caffe
but it does not work at all

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no currently supported solution to convert an ONNX model to a Caffe model.

There is the [Caffe -> ONNX direction](https://github.com/onnx/onnx-docker/blob/master/onnx-ecosystem/converter_scripts/caffe_coreml_onnx.ipynb), using both onnxmltools and coremltools.